# MongoDB - How to unwind object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, aggregation-framework

I am trying to manipulate a dataset to make it easy to display in mongoCharts. There are two sets of team_a and team_b, each contains a set of playerId, score, rank, and prize. I want to unwind the array inside the Object and also want to merge both arrays into one.

Sample Document:

```
{
  team_a: {
    team_score: 94,
    team_name: "team_1",
    players: [
      {
        id: "604f00d43776e45a448628f9",
        username: "test_1",
        score: "33",
        rank: "1",
        prize: 15.4,
      },
      {
        id: "60058dd9b88cc1a1e40f2f54",
        username: "test_2",
        score: "31",
        rank: "2",
        prize: 15.4,
      },
      {
        id: "60058dd9b88cc1a1e40f2f55",
        username: "test_3",
        score: "30",
        rank: "3",
        prize: 15.4,
      }
    ],
  },
  team_b: {
    team_score: 62,
    team_name: "team_2",
    players: [
      {
        id: "602ce34a39c7496600940774",
        username: "test_4",
        score: "32",
        rank: "1",
      },
      {
        id: "60058db6b88cc1a1e40f2f4f",
        username: "test_5",
        score: "30",
        rank: "2",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

And the desired output is:

```
{
    team_a: [
      {
          username: "test_1",
          score: "33",
          rank: "1",
          prize: 15.4,
      },
      {
          username: "test_2",
          score: "31",
          rank: "2",
          prize: 15.4,
       },
       {
         username: "test_3",
         score: "30",
         rank: "3",
         prize: 15.4,
      }
    ],
    team_b: [
      {
         username: "test_4",
         score: "32",
         rank: "1",
      },
      {
        username: "test_5",
        score: "30",
        rank: "2",
       },
    ],
    all_winners: [
        {
          username: "test_1",
          score: "33",
          rank: "1",
          prize: 15.4,
        },
        {
          username: "test_2",
          score: "31",
          rank: "2",
          prize: 15.4,
        },
        {
          username: "test_3",
          score: "30",
          rank: "3",
          prize: 15.4,
        }
        {
          username: "test_4",
          score: "31",
          rank: "4",
        },
        {
          username: "test_5",
          score: "30",
          rank: "5",
        },
    ]
}
```

Any guidance or pointers are gratefully received.
Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

1st `$project` stage:

1. `team_a` field with `team_a.players`
2. `team_b` field with `team_b.players`
3. `all_winners` field with [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) for `team_a.players` and `team_b.players`

2nd `$project` stage:

- Remove `id` field from `team_a`, `team_b`, `all_winners` array fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "team_a": "$team_a.players",
      "team_b": "$team_b.players",
      "all_winners": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$team_a.players",
          "$team_b.players"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "all_winners": {
        id: 0
      },
      "team_a": {
        id: 0
      },
      "team_b": {
        id: 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nIiIAr-zy8h)

---

### Solution 2

Alternative, use `$unset` to remove `team_a.players.id` and `team_b.players.id` as first stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unset: [
      "team_a.players.id",
      "team_b.players.id"
    ]
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "team_a": "$team_a.players",
      "team_b": "$team_b.players",
      "all_winners": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$team_a.players",
          "$team_b.players"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dz-QhTPDXuP)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I just had edited the question pls have a look now, and could you tell me what is a possible way to achieve this now.

Comment: Hi, I saw your change, you added username field in each player document. Would say that the above query would include the username field as well. Is the above query meets your requirements?

Comment: Yes, in the above query I have id and usernames, but in the final data I just want limited output like no ids just username, score, rank, and prize

Comment: @SuneelKKhatri just project it with the above code https://mongoplayground.net/p/rMTPcgtjrNF

Comment: Hi Suneel, I updated my answer. And thanks @varman again for the rescue. =)